# Grails: Strange IOException that occurs rarely when trying to issue the run-app target

Tags: grails

Every once in a while I have seen this error when issuing the `grails run-app` target:

```
| Error Error executing script RunApp: : IOException in C:\Users\user\Dropbox\Code\Projects\qotd\target\work\web.xml.tmp - java.io.FileNotFoundException:C:\Users\user
\Dropbox\Code\Projects\qotd\target\work\web.xml.tmp (Access is denied) (Use --sta
cktrace to see the full trace)
```

and so far it appears I can always get around it by issuing `grails run-app` again. If possible I would like to know what is the mechanism causing this error and why does it seem to disappear/correct by itself. Thanks.

Edit: Is it possible that this error is generated because since I keep my project in my Dropbox folder, I may sometimes invoke the `grails run-app` target while something in Dropbox is still syncing?

Comment: Can't be a dropbox thing, I just got it running grails 2.4.4 locally.  I tried to run again with --stacktrace but the project started fine.  +1 for whoever can shed light on this